# Since Spring, various websites have stopped working properly (on Safari and Opera) on my iPhone 8 running iOS 12

Tags: ios, safari, javascript

Since Spring, various websites have stopped working properly (on Safari and Opera) on my iPhone 8 running iOS 12. No problems on Android or MacOS.

I suspect JavaScript (grey buttons don't go red when clicked, merely darker grey; popup menus don't popup; button have no effect etc). Are servers serving upgraded JavaScript code?

Would upgrading to iOS 16 help? If possible I would like to avoid this because of other software becoming unavailable.

Comment: Can you add some examples (links) of such sites?

Comment: @nohillside https://www.theguardian.com/international

Comment: All I can say is that this site works with iOS 16.

Comment: It works OK on an old Mac running Mojave & Safari 14 too - usually I get fails on modern WebP & WebM structures, so at least it rules that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

I upgraded the iPhone to version 16.6. I no longer have the problem with Safari and Opera. And I didn't have anticipated problems with other software (but I have later discovered that the battery runs down in half the time).

I hate the new user interface and graphic design though. :(